# Read txt files, results in empty lines

Tags: python

I have some problem to open and read a txt-file in Python. The txt file contains text (cat text.txt works fine in Terminal). But in Python I only get 5 empty lines.

```
print open('text.txt').read()
```

Do you know why?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the txt file might contain?

Comment: Is there more to your program or is it just that one line?

Comment: Are you sure the read method can be chained to the open method?

Have you tried

file = open('text.txt')
print file.read()

Comment: @mnemosdev That is valid statement. I've done this many tmes, however there is something else that is wrong

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Would be helpful if OP could post the entire code, if there exists more of it. Otherwise it makes me think that the OP does not have python installed on his computer, which could also be a possibility

Comment: @mnemosdev `OP does not have python installed on his computer` :D

Comment: @mnemosdev: You sure do think outside the box!

Comment: Just for the sake of trying, the code on my mac works just fine from the Python console, so I would really think about the possibility of Python not being installed XD

Comment: i suspect you might open a different file with the same name. your program might have changed directory.

Comment: It is strange that people ask question and then they go to bed, we keep on bumping our heads here, asking more about question. :(

Answer (score 4):

I solved it. Was a utf-16 file.

```
print open('text.txt').read().decode('utf-16-le')
```

Comment: ahh... sorry, shoulda thought of encoding ._.

Answer (score 2):

if this prints the lines in your file then perhaps the file your program is selecting is empty? I don't know, but try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

def fileopen():
    GUI=tk.Tk()
    filepath=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=GUI,title='Select file to print lines.')
    (GUI).destroy()
    return (filepath)

filepath = fileopen()
filepath = os.path.normpath(filepath)

with open (filepath, 'r') as fh:
    print (fh.read())
```

or alternatively, using this method of printing lines:

```
fh = open(filepath, 'r')
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip('\n')
    print (line)
fh.close()
```

or if you want the lines loaded into a list of strings:

```
lines = []
fh = open(filepath, 'r')
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip('\n')
    lines.append(line)
fh.close()

for line in lines:
    print (line)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you open file I think you have to specify how do you want to open it. In your example you should open it for reading like:

```
print open('text.txt',"r").read()
```

Hope this does the trick.